# Kafka consumer does not poll records intermittently

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have wrote a simple utility in scala to read kafka message as byte array.

The utility works on one machine but not on the other. Both are on same OS (centos 7) and same kafka server as well (which is in another machine all together).

However Kafka Tool (www.kafkatool.com) works on the machine which the utility not - so its not likely accessibility issue.

Following is the essence of the consumer code:

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer

val outputFile = "output.txt"
val topic = "test_topic"
val server = "localhost:9092"
val id = "record-tool"

val props = new Properties()
props.put("bootstrap.servers", server)
props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer")
props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false")
props.put("max.partition.fetch.bytes", "104857600")
props.put("group.id", id)

val bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile))
val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, Array[Byte]](props)
consumer.subscribe(Seq(topic).asJava)
Stream.continually(consumer.poll(5000).asScala.toList).takeWhile(_.nonEmpty).flatten.foreach(c => bos.write(c.value)))
consumer.close
bos.close
```

I dont see any errors in the logs as well, following is debug log

```
[root@vm util]# bin/record-tool consume --server=kafka-server:9092 --topic=test_topic --asBin --debug

16:44:02.548 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig - ConsumerConfig values: 
    metric.reporters = []
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 104857600
    bootstrap.servers = [kafka-server:9092]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    enable.auto.commit = false
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    interceptor.classes = null
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    client.id = 
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    max.poll.records = 2147483647
    check.crcs = true
    request.timeout.ms = 40000
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    group.id = record-tool
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.key.password = null
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    session.timeout.ms = 30000
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest

16:44:02.550 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - Starting the Kafka consumer
16:44:02.621 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - Updated cluster metadata version 1 to Cluster(nodes = [kafka-server:9092 (id: -1 rack: null)], partitions = [])
16:44:02.632 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name connections-closed:
16:44:02.636 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name connections-created:
16:44:02.637 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name bytes-sent-received:
16:44:02.637 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name bytes-sent:
16:44:02.638 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name bytes-received:
16:44:02.638 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name select-time:
16:44:02.639 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name io-time:
16:44:02.649 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig - ConsumerConfig values: 
    metric.reporters = []
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 104857600
    bootstrap.servers = [kafka-server:9092]
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    enable.auto.commit = false
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    interceptor.classes = null
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    client.id = consumer-1
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
    max.poll.records = 2147483647
    check.crcs = true
    request.timeout.ms = 40000
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    group.id = record-tool
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.key.password = null
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    session.timeout.ms = 30000
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest

16:44:02.657 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name heartbeat-latency
16:44:02.657 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name join-latency
16:44:02.657 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name sync-latency
16:44:02.659 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name commit-latency
16:44:02.663 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name bytes-fetched
16:44:02.664 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name records-fetched
16:44:02.664 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name fetch-latency
16:44:02.664 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name records-lag
16:44:02.664 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name fetch-throttle-time
16:44:02.666 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version : 0.10.0.1
16:44:02.666 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId : a7a17cdec9eaa6c5
16:44:02.668 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - Kafka consumer created
16:44:02.680 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - Subscribed to topic(s): test_topic
16:44:02.681 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - Sending coordinator request for group record-tool to broker kafka-server:9092 (id: -1 rack: null)
16:44:02.695 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initiating connection to node -1 at kafka-server:9092.
16:44:02.816 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-sent
16:44:02.817 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name node--1.bytes-received
16:44:02.818 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name node--1.latency
16:44:02.820 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Completed connection to node -1
16:44:02.902 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Sending metadata request {topics=[test_topic]} to node -1
16:44:02.981 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - Updated cluster metadata version 2 to Cluster(nodes = [kafka-server.mydomain.com:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)], partitions = [Partition(topic = test_topic, partition = 0, leader = 0, replicas = [0,], isr = [0,]])
16:44:02.982 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - Received group coordinator response ClientResponse(receivedTimeMs=1583225042982, disconnected=false, request=ClientRequest(expectResponse=true, callback=org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient$RequestFutureCompletionHandler@434a63ab, request=RequestSend(header={api_key=10,api_version=0,correlation_id=0,client_id=consumer-1}, body={group_id=record-tool}), createdTimeMs=1583225042692, sendTimeMs=1583225042904), responseBody={error_code=0,coordinator={node_id=0,host=kafka-server.mydomain.com,port=9092}})
16:44:02.983 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - Discovered coordinator kafka-server.mydomain.com:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) for group record-tool.
16:44:02.983 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initiating connection to node 2147483647 at kafka-server.mydomain.com:9092.
16:44:02.986 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - Revoking previously assigned partitions [] for group record-tool
16:44:02.986 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - (Re-)joining group record-tool
16:44:02.988 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - Sending JoinGroup ({group_id=record-tool,session_timeout=30000,member_id=,protocol_type=consumer,group_protocols=[{protocol_name=range,protocol_metadata=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=25 cap=25]}]}) to coordinator kafka-server.mydomain.com:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
16:44:03.051 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name node-2147483647.bytes-sent
16:44:03.051 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name node-2147483647.bytes-received
16:44:03.052 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name node-2147483647.latency
16:44:03.052 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Completed connection to node 2147483647
16:44:03.123 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - Received successful join group response for group record-tool: {error_code=0,generation_id=3,group_protocol=range,leader_id=consumer-1-f82633ab-a06e-4474-8ddb-1ec096d6c7f2,member_id=consumer-1-f82633ab-a06e-4474-8ddb-1ec096d6c7f2,members=[{member_id=consumer-1-f82633ab-a06e-4474-8ddb-1ec096d6c7f2,member_metadata=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=25 cap=25]}]}
16:44:03.123 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - Performing assignment for group record-tool using strategy range with subscriptions {consumer-1-f82633ab-a06e-4474-8ddb-1ec096d6c7f2=Subscription(topics=[test_topic])}
16:44:03.124 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - Finished assignment for group record-tool: {consumer-1-f82633ab-a06e-4474-8ddb-1ec096d6c7f2=Assignment(partitions=[test_topic-0])}
16:44:03.124 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - Sending leader SyncGroup for group record-tool to coordinator kafka-server.mydomain.com:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null): {group_id=record-tool,generation_id=3,member_id=consumer-1-f82633ab-a06e-4474-8ddb-1ec096d6c7f2,group_assignment=[{member_id=consumer-1-f82633ab-a06e-4474-8ddb-1ec096d6c7f2,member_assignment=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=33 cap=33]}]}
16:44:03.198 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - Successfully joined group record-tool with generation 3
16:44:03.199 [main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - Setting newly assigned partitions [test_topic-0] for group record-tool
16:44:03.200 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - Group record-tool fetching committed offsets for partitions: [test_topic-0]
16:44:03.268 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - Group record-tool has no committed offset for partition test_topic-0
16:44:03.269 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - Resetting offset for partition test_topic-0 to earliest offset.
16:44:03.270 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Initiating connection to node 0 at kafka-server.mydomain.com:9092.
16:44:03.336 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name node-0.bytes-sent
16:44:03.337 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name node-0.bytes-received
16:44:03.337 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name node-0.latency
16:44:03.338 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Completed connection to node 0
16:44:03.407 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - Fetched offset 0 for partition test_topic-0
16:44:06.288 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - Received successful heartbeat response for group record-tool
16:44:07.702 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Removed sensor with name connections-closed:
16:44:07.702 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Removed sensor with name connections-created:
16:44:07.702 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Removed sensor with name bytes-sent-received:
16:44:07.702 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Removed sensor with name bytes-sent:
16:44:07.703 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Removed sensor with name bytes-received:
16:44:07.703 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Removed sensor with name select-time:
16:44:07.704 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Removed sensor with name io-time:
16:44:07.704 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Removed sensor with name node--1.bytes-sent
16:44:07.705 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Removed sensor with name node--1.bytes-received
16:44:07.705 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Removed sensor with name node--1.latency
16:44:07.705 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Removed sensor with name node-2147483647.bytes-sent
16:44:07.706 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Removed sensor with name node-2147483647.bytes-received
16:44:07.706 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Removed sensor with name node-2147483647.latency
16:44:07.706 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Removed sensor with name node-0.bytes-sent
16:44:07.707 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Removed sensor with name node-0.bytes-received
16:44:07.707 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Removed sensor with name node-0.latency
16:44:07.707 [main] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - The Kafka consumer has closed.
```

What I noticed within `takeWhile(_.nonEmpty)` is the list is empty.

Is there any mistake in the code? Thanks.

Comment: Did both the Kafka consumers read from same topic?

Comment: @AnandSai Yes and from exact same offset as well since this util does not commit.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the issue that you are facing?

Comment: @AnandSai The util above suppose to produce output file containing byte arrays read from kafka. However, on these runs i get a zero size output file despite no errors in kafka consumer log.

Comment: Please show topic description and consumer group lag